# Reproduce the functionality of mysql_fetch_object()

Tags: php

I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of `mysql_fetch_object()`. If I understand well, what it does is returns the MySQL query as an object of stdClass if you no param or of another class if you give it.

I say I need to reproduce because I need to hack a class to do this thing with Mongo. I explain myself.

I get results from Mongo actually as an array, I need them to retrive it as an stdClass or a class I pass to this function. How I can do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the resultent array into object

```
$result= (object) $result_array;
```

Comment: and if I don't want stdClass and i want an object with a name like Model_Example? thank you

Answer (score 3):

Passing by stdClass can be done by casting to (object).

`$object = (object)$array;`

Any other class is possible, but I don't recommend it. I've written something that does it: [Make my own (non-database) fetch_object function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424530/make-my-own-non-database-fetch-object-function)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function array_to_object($array = array()) {
    if (!empty($array)) {
        $data = false;
        foreach ($array as $akey => $aval) {
            $data -> {$akey} = $aval;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call the result of that function using:

```
$newObj = array_to_object($yourArray);
$newObj->SomeField = ...;
```

Edit: lol, really, all it takes is `$obj = (object)$array`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = new StdClass;
$result->foo = 'Lorem ipsum';
$result->bar = 'Dolor sit amet';
var_dump($result);
```

... or simply cast something else as object:

```
$result = (object)NULL;
$result->foo = 'Lorem ipsum';
$result->bar = 'Dolor sit amet';
var_dump($result);
```

Both snippets print the same output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
  ["bar"]=>
  string(14) "Dolor sit amet"
}
```